# aggregating a data frame over a column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame, one of the columns representing years. Let's say

```
region <- c("Spain", "Italy", "Norway")
year   <- c("2010","2011","2012","2010","2011","2012","2010","2011","2012")
m1     <- c("10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
m2     <- c("20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100")
data   <- data.frame(region,year,m1,m2)
```

I want to aggregate the data set `m1` in a way taking 3-year averages for each country. I am confused in how to do that with a data frame. Any comment is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show here a portion of your data.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `m1` variable needs to be numeric. Convert it using `as.numeric()`:

```
data$m1 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$m1))
```

Then, you can use `aggregate` like this:

```
aggregate(m1 ~ region, FUN = mean, data = data)

#   region m1
# 1  Italy 14
# 2 Norway 15
# 3  Spain 13
```

To avoid the awkward type conversion (`as.numeric(as.character())`), you should eliminate the quotes from the setup for `m1` and `m2`:

```
m1     <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)
m2     <- c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
```

---

Alternative approach using [`dplyr`](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

```
library(dplyr)

region <- c("Spain", "Italy", "Norway")
year   <- c("2010","2011","2012","2010","2011","2012","2010","2011","2012")
m1     <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)
m2     <- c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
data   <- data.frame(region,year,m1,m2)

data %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise(mean_m1 = mean(m1),
            mean_m2 = mean(m2))

#   region mean_m1 mean_m2
# 1  Italy      14      60
# 2 Norway      15      70
# 3  Spain      13      50
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks a lot! As I was confused which part of the aggregate function tells R to take the average over the set "year", I noticed that the output was not correct, either. It should be Spain=11, Italy=14, Norway=17. I guess I can move forward from here but just wanted to note that the answer is not what the question asks exactly. Thanks!

Comment: @Dilara Good catch. Fixed the code. The error has to do with converting a factor variable to a numerical variable - this requires that you first convert to character before converting to a numeric (which I fixed) - however, as I noted at the bottom of my answer, you may be better off removing the quotes from your setup to avoid the conversion altogether.

Comment: yeah, runs now, thanks! Can "mean" also be used for defining averages over a subset of a set, i.e. our set was {2010,2011,2012}, and if we want 2 year averages over the subset {2010,2011}?

Comment: @Dilara Yes, simply use the `subset` function. `subset(data, year %in% c("2010", "2011"))`. If you prefer the `dplyr` approach, you could use `filter()`. For completeness, aggregating over a subset would be: `aggregate(m1 ~ region, data = subset(data, year %in% c("2010", "2011")), FUN = mean)` - note, you can pass any function into the `FUN` argument, such as `sum` or `var` or `sd`.